# Images for retina display iphone

Tags: iphone, xcode, interface-builder, iphone-4, retina-display

I have an working application which i have tested in my ipod touch. Everything works pretty fine.

My tabbar icons and splash screen images are in a separate folder in my Resources folder

```
Resources->images
```

Now, I know for iPhone4 i need to use 2x images.

My question is for support for iPhone4 all that i need to do is add 2x images in my images folder. For example if my splashscreen image is **Default.png**, I should add my 2x image as **Default@2x.png** in my images folder and iphone will use it automatically.?

Is it the same for all tabbar images ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, all that you said is correct. Remember to also import the `@2x` images into your Xcode project (e.g. by dragging them from Finder to Xcode), so they'll be added to the bundle when you build your app.

Comment: thanks for your reply. For my tabBar icon i have used an image "icon_tab_1_30x30.png" in my interface builder. Now i add "icon_tab_1_30x30@2x.png"..Should i change the naming in the interface builder like its said in the answer below ??

Comment: @Narayanan: No. You don't need to change anything in Interface Builder.

Answer (score 9):

For the apps I have worked on, I have only one image in this format:

```
myImage@2x.png
```

When I reference this image, I make the following call and it always works, whether on a 3GS/iPhone 4 or iPad.

```
[UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage.png"]
```

Comment: On non-Retina devices, if iOS can't find the standard images it will still look for the `@2x` versions and grab them. However, they get downsampled, and may not look right (or at least not look great).

Comment: you mean to say you dont have myImage.png at all ?

Comment: Correct - I only call the plain version (without @2x) but the only images referenced and linked to Xcode are the @2x versions.

Comment: and iphone downscales it automatically. wow. Thanks for the information. Should save binary file size :-)

Comment: It's an easy way to do indeed, but delivering the non-retina image makes the app more lightweight.