# Image blurry in retina Display on appstore

Tags: ios, image

I have created a universal app. I have used the same images in both iPhone and iPad screens with same dimensions. For Retina display, I have added the @2x images. Everything works fine on simulator as well as device when we run the test app.

But after uploading on Appstore the app downloaded in the device shows poor quality images for retina displays.

Thanks in Advance!!!

[image]

Comment: If your retina device runs iOS 4.0, maybe that question/answer addresses your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3442239/retina-icons-2x-arent-being-used-when-images-are-specified-in-code

Comment: The device is running on iOS 5.1

Comment: Does it work when you build and deploy directly to your device?

Comment: @David yes it works fine when I run and deploy in device.

Comment: Can you show an example of how exactly you've incorporated "@2x" into your file names?

Comment: Do you have one target for testing and for distribution, or two? The logical answer is that the retina images didn't make it into your app bundle when you went to upload.

Comment: Stupid question but your device does have a retina screen?

If you still have the zip file that you uploaded to Apple you can unpack it with any zip program and check the contents to make sure that the images were included when you sent it to Apple.

Comment: @David I have only one target in my project.

Comment: @NSPostWhenIdle Attached is my screenshot. The images are for both iPhone and iPad. Dimensions of icons are same for both iPhone and iPad.

Comment: So find the .ipa file that got uploaded, change the file extension from .ipa to .zip, dbl click it in finder, you will get a Payload directory, open it, then click on app and enter "Show Package Contents", see if the retina images are in fact there. Also, for all retina images, verify they are included in the one target by selecting them one at a time in the left pane, then opening the right pane and selecting the top left "File" option - you will see a box "Target Membership" and the box better be checked.

Comment: Some of the links says we need to add ~ipad along with @2x for iPad. Currently I am not doing this.Can this be reason for my issue? I don't have a way to confirm this as issue occurs only after we submit App to Appstore.

Comment: The only reason for ~ipad is to differentiate it from different image used on the iphone (which can itself be either plain - foo.png - or foo~iphone.png. If you only have normal/retina images, you just need those two. If you have different images (or sizes) then you would have 4 total.